# In xhtml is this correct syntax of unchecked radio button

Tags: forms, checkbox, xhtml, radio-button

In XHTML I know that this is correct for a checked radion button:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="bar" value="baz" />
```

And absence of the checked attribute means that the radio button is unchecked:

```
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="baz" />
```

But would this be correct for unchecked radio button as well:

```
<input type="radio" checked="" name="bar" value="baz" />
```

Comment: in XHTML you should end an input tag with  />

Comment: But my guess is your last line might not work, even if it looks ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No actually using

```
<input type="radio" checked="" name="bar" value="baz" />
```

will also render the checkbox checked in the browsers i've seen (how strange it might look)!

Comment: I believe you are right / could have to do with backward compatibility

Comment: Yes you will have to take away the attribute completely not just the value in order to get the checkbox unchecked - this applies to strict XHTML as well. (Probably due to backward compatibility as you suggest)